# Xamarin is displaying photos with a random rotation

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.mobile

I'm working with a hybrid xamarin application. The pictures stored in my decvices (like images) are displayed good, but the photos (new photos or photos stored in my device) when I display those images, are displayed with a rotation of 45° or 90°, but is very randomically and only with the photos. 
And I tried adding css code like:

```
rotation: 0deg;
```

For the photos but always the same problem.
Some one has an idea about the problem?

Comment: Sounds like your image are being shown with their physical rotation, not the logical one (i.e. EXIF tag). Without seeing the code it's hard to say where that information (converting image likely) was lost.

Comment: If I checked the image directly in the server are ok, but for some reason in the browser (mobile browser) are rotated. I'm not sure if the metadata in the image has relevance

Comment: With your phone take four pictures, rotating the phone 90 degrees each time. Now open each picture in your browser (or with other software). You'll see the ones that shows you the picture **as-is** and the one that reads the orientation from the metadata.